Make django middleware variables able to handle concurrent requests
I have to implement a custom middleware in django to count the number of requests served so far. It is a part of an assignment that I've got.
I have created the middleware like this
# myapp/middleware.py

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class RequestCounterMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    request_count = 0

    def process_request(self, request):
        RequestCounterMiddleware.request_count += 1

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        return response

    @staticmethod
    def get_request_count():
        return RequestCounterMiddleware.request_count

Now my question is how to make the variable request_count able to handle concurrent requests and show the correct value.
ChatGPT suggested using threading.Lock(). Would that be a good option? If not, please suggest some other way. Thanks :)
EDIT: This question is not similar to implementing a counter that counts requests with django because here we are taking concurrent requests into consideration.

the most known way is using Redis cache atomic increment. you can ask this redis cache way to chatgpt and get an answer

This question is similar to: implementing a counter that counts requests with django. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here's a hint, stop trying to store this information in a variable if you want to do it reliably. In a real / production deployment it is very likely that you'll end up having multiple Django processes causing this naive counting strategy to give you wrong results. Consider storing this in the database or a cache (like Redis).

Guys, I went ahead with Redis cache atomic increment. Seems to work for the assignment.
